# Array disappear in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm writing a script to collect some various network statistics.
What I'm trying to do is to produce some delta data from the netstat -i command.

I'm collecting the needed data with the following bash code:

```
declare -a array
n=0
netstat -i | tail -n +3 | while read LINE; do
        echo "Setting array[$n] to $LINE"
        array[$n]=$LINE
        echo "array now have ${#array[@]} entries"
        let n=$n+1
done
echo "array now have ${#array[@]} entries"
```

output from this command is:

```
Setting array[0] to eth0       1500 0   4946794      0      0 0       2522971      0      0      0 BMRU
array now have 1 entries
Setting array[1] to lo        16436 0     25059      0      0 0         25059      0      0      0 LRU
array now have 2 entries
Setting array[2] to vmnet1     1500 0         6      0      0 0          1126      0      0      0 BMRU
array now have 3 entries
Setting array[3] to vmnet8     1500 0       955      0      0 0          1054      0      0      0 BMRU
array now have 4 entries
Setting array[4] to wlan0      1500 0    613879      0      0 0        351194      0      0      0 BMU
array now have 5 entries
array now have 0 entries
```

As you can see, the array actually disappear after the while loop, and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you use a pipe you create an implicit subshell. When that subshell terminates, so do its variables. A quick fix for this is to not pipe stuff to `read`. You can accomplish the above using process substitution:

```
while read LINE; do
        echo "Setting array[$n] to $LINE"
        array[$n]=$LINE
        echo "array now have ${#array[@]} entries"
        let n=$n+1
done < <(netstat -i | tail -n +3)
```

A more POSIX compliant approach (read: more portable, less bashist) is to make everything happen in the subshell:

```
netstat -i | tail -n +3 | {
    declare -a array
    n=0
    while read LINE; do
        echo "Setting array[$n] to $LINE"
        array[$n]=$LINE
        echo "array now have ${#array[@]} entries"
        let n=$n+1
    done
    echo "array now have ${#array[@]} entries"
}
```

You can read the fine points of this (and more) at [Greg Wooledge's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Thanks, the first code works perfectly. But the array is lost outside the subshell. I suspect this is the intention, but does not work for me.

Comment: Very nice. I prefer the POSIX compliant approach because it provides the input data at the start, supporting chronological reading.

Comment: @Arthur you can provide the input data at the start either way. `< <(netstat …) while read LINE; do …`

Answer (score 2):

If your only goal is to put the output of a command into an array (linewise), you'd better use the (sadly not very well-known) `mapfile` bash builtin, it's by far the most efficient (and the best suited for code golf, count how many character strokes I have compared to the other possibilities):

```
mapfile -t array < <(netstat -i | tail -n +3)
```

The other answers explain why your construct didn't work (pipe is in a subshell and all that).

`help mapfile` for all the details and possibilities of that command.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, are you ready?

There is how to transform `netstat -i | tail -n +3` in a **bash** Associative Array of array:

```
declare -A AANET
while read -a line ;do
    declare -a AI$line
    eval "AI$line=(${line[@]})"
    AANET[$line]=AI$line
  done < <(
    netstat -i |
       tail -n +3)
```

Than now:

```
echo ${!AANET[@]}
venet0 eth1 eth0 lo br0

echo ${AANET[eth0]}
AIeth0
```

And for *sub-associative*, we have to use `eval`:

```
eval echo \${${AANET[eth0]}[@]}
eth0 1500 0 17647 0 0 0 35426 0 0 0 BMPU

eval echo \${${AANET[eth0]}[1]}
1500

eval echo \${${AANET[eth0]}[3]}
17647

eval echo \${${AANET[eth0]}[7]}
35426

eval echo \${${AANET[eth0]}[@]:3:5}
17647 0 0 0 35426
```

An for assing a temporary variable:

```
eval currentBin=\${${AANET[eth0]}[3]} currentBout=\${${AANET[eth0]}[7]}
echo $currentBout 
35426
echo $currentBin 
17647
```

or even too:

```
eval "declare -a currentVals=(\${${AANET[eth0]}[@]:3:8})"
echo ${currentVals[0]}
17647
echo ${currentVals[4]}
35426
echo ${currentVals[@]}
17647 0 0 0 35426 0 0 0
```

**Edit**:

Ok, if it is possible **without** `eval`!

```
for aKey in ${!AANET[@]};do
    fields=(${AANET[$aKey]}{[1],[3],[7]});
    echo $aKey ${!fields} ${!fields[1]} ${!fields[2]}
  done |
    xargs printf "%-9s %12s %12s %12s\n" IFace MTU RX TX

IFace              MTU           RX           TX
venet0            1500            0            0
eth1              1500      6400292      6942577
eth0              1500        17647        35426
lo               16436           83           83
```

Comment: Too much `eval` for me `:-(`. Bash was never designed for that kind of stuff. If you really need these constructs, just use another language.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Are you comming from *php*? You could use `eval` in such case where you know which kind of data could be *evalued*. In this situation, command `netstat -i` won't return backtick or such *cross-scripting* echapments.

Comment: Nope, not coming from php at all. Just that I know what language is suited for what task (or at least, I believe I do).

Comment: Btw, you can achieve the same without any `eval`'s (using indirect expansion), but what's the point anyways?

Comment: How do you do that? (using indirect expansion)

Comment: It's not really the purpose of this post to explain that but something around this (that will be safe regarding everything): `array=(field0 field1); name="array[@]"; echo "${!name}"; keyfield0=0; namefield0="array[0]"; echo "${!namefield0}"`, then build up on this (with helper functions).

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf! +1 for the idea to call sub array with *indirect expansion*! At all, I persist: for monitoring tools that parse known commands results, `eval` could be usefull! Of course, you have to *know what you're doing* before you use eval. You could even *sanitize* your feed before of using *dangerous method*...

Answer (score 0):

Don't pipe to a loop, bash substitutes variables first and then starts a subshell without access to your array.

Do it like this. Nice and simple.

```
array=()
for alias in `netstat -i | tail -n +3`; do
    array+=($alias)
done
echo ${array[@]}
```